# Fancybox 2 width bug

Tags: jquery, fancybox, responsive-design, fancybox-2

I'm using Fancybox 2 for it's ability to resize images to the viewport. However, I have a few images that are extremely wide (1000 x 100) and they aren't resizing properly. They are displaying huge (apparently resizing to fit the entire width of the monitor?). The coding is all correct and working properly with other images...the only difference is the extreme width.

Is there a way to correct this or am I going to have to give up on fancybox?

Comment: Is there a way you can show the code you are using or a link to the page with the issue or a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem? personally I don't think there is a bug (unless you prove me wrong ;)

Comment: Sure. Check an example out here: http://www.emilywatanabe.com/fancybox/fancybox.htm

Comment: As you can see, the second image works fine, but the first does not resize properly to fit the viewport.

Comment: It does fit the viewport "horizontally" and keeps the aspect ratio of your original image, which is 3314x600px. If that image wasn't fitting the vievport then you should see horizontal scroll bars in your browser. What result were you expecting?

Comment: I actually DO see a horizontal scroll bar, which is what I don't want. Try sizing down the viewport a lot and let me know if the wide image resizes horizontally...because it doesn't on my computer.

Comment: The image does resize when I expand the viewport, but when I shrink it, it fails to resize. Here's a screenshot of the problem I'm experiencing: http://imgur.com/lNhtriy

Comment: I have encountered this issue in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (all up-to-date), so I don't think it's a browser issue.

Comment: OK, I see know. It's not a bug .... is just other things that you are not taking in consideration. I will post an answer and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments area, fancybox is capable to fit images into the viewport, including those wide images as in your [example](http://www.emilywatanabe.com/fancybox/fancybox.htm).

The reasons why your example doesn't work as expected are :

1). You are missing a proper `DOCTYPE`. Chrome and other browsers, including Opera and IE, definitively won't play nice without this requirement.

2). Images will scale to small screens UNLESS they have either a `min-width` and/or `min-height` css properties. In other words, if the `min-height` of an image is `200px`, then the image won't down-scale its `width` if the `height` matches the minimum set, regardless that you keep shrinking the viewport. That is the case of your wide image.

If you check the **[fancybox documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)**, you will find two properties with their default settings :

```
minWidth   Minimum width fancyBox should be allowed to resize to; 
           Default value: 100 

minHeight  Minimum height fancyBox should be allowed to resize to; 
           Default value: 100
```

What you can do is to modify those default settings within your own fancybox custom script like :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.fancybox').fancybox({
         minWidth: 10, // you can scale images as small as 10px wide
         minHeight: 10 // you can scale images as small as 10px height
     });
 });
```

See **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/widthBug_30mar13.html)** and play shrinking the viewport with Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Ah, I thought it might have something to do with a min-height. Thanks for you help! :)